# Update row when edit button is pressed and save in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new to jquery and javascript. The final function that i needed help is after clicking the edit button you can update both textboxes and save it, but I need it to display the updated row from which  table row it was placed, not after updating it and display it on the bottom of the table. Here is what my code looks like. Thanks.

```js
function remove(deletelink) {
  $(deletelink).closest("tr").remove();
  if ($("tbody").find("tr").length == 0) {
    $("tbody").append("<tr id='nomore'><td colspan='4'>No more records.</td></tr>");
  }
  return false;
}

function edit(editlink) {
  var name = $(editlink).closest("tr").find("td.name").text();
  var course = $(editlink).closest("tr").find("td.course").text();

  $("#name").val(name);
  $("#course").val(course);
  $("#button").val("SAVE");
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".delete").click(function() {
    remove(this);
  });

  $(".edit").click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var tds = $this.closest('tr').find('td').filter(function() {
      return $(this).find('.edit').length === 0;
    });
    if ($this.html() === 'edit') {
      $this.html('save');
      tds.prop('contenteditable', true);
    } else {
      $this.html('edit');
      tds.prop('contenteditable', false);
    }

    edit(this);
  });

  $("#button").click(function() {
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var course = $("#course").val();

    if ($("tbody").find("tr#nomore").length > 0) {
      $("tbody").html("");
    }

    $("tbody").append("<tr><td class='name'>" + name + "</td><td class='course'>" + course + "</td><td><a href='#' class='edit'>Edit</a></td><td><a href='#' class='delete'>Delete</a></td></tr>");
    $(".delete").click(function() {});
    $(".delete").click(function() {
      remove(this);
    });

    $(".edit").click(function() {});
    $(".edit").click(function() {
      edit(this);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name" />
<input type="text" id="course" placeholder="Course" />
<input type="button" id="button" value="ADD" />
<br /><br />
<table border="1" cellpadding="3">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Course</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="name">Joaquin</td>
      <td class="course">BSIT</td>
      <td>
        <a href="#" class="edit">Edit</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="name">Jump</td>
      <td class="course">BSIT</td>
      <td>
        <a href="#" class="edit">Edit</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="name">Ersan</td>
      <td class="course">BSHRM</td>
      <td>
        <a href="#" class="edit">Edit</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="name">Laree</td>
      <td class="course">BSIT</td>
      <td>
        <a href="#" class="edit">Edit</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please reduce your question to only the issue at hand, as you should as per [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it's difficult to sift through all your code as of now

Comment: You need to use some kind of templating framework for this. JQuery is old and not suited for this kind of work.

Comment: @Miguel I disagree, while a templating framework, or a javascript framework (angular, react vue etc.) would be a solution. I think Jquery or plain old vanilla js is certainly up to the task

Comment: @BryanDellinger I never said JQuery couldn't do it. I said it wasn't suited for this kind of work. Context switching is easier done with a framework that supports data binding. And employers aren't looking for JQuery professionals. They prefer people who are better with core JS.

Answer (score 0):

how about something like this

https://jsfiddle.net/e864uvn7/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   let row = null

   $('.edit').click(function() {
     row = $(this).closest('tr');
     $('#a').val(row.find('td:eq(0)').text())
     $('#b').val(row.find('td:eq(1)').text())
   });

   $('#submit').click(function() {
     if (row) {
       row.find('td:eq(0)').text($('#a').val());
       row.find('td:eq(1)').text($('#b').val());
       $('#a').val('');
       $('#b').val('');
     }
   })


 });
```